# How to create an editor for a string containing a serialized class in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, polymorphism, editorfor

I have a string property in my ViewModel which contains a serialized representation of one of ten possible classes, each class is very different so there is no base class for them.

```
public string Configuration { get; set; }
public string ConfigurationType { get; set;}
```

Ideally I would like to create a different editor template for each of the classes that could be deserialized into the property and them simply have

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(l => l.Configuration)%>
```

Where I could somehow inform mvc that Configuration needs to be deserialized into an object of ConfigurationType for it to use the correct template and then deserialize back to a string again.

I appreciate that I'm light on details here but I'd like to keep things as abstract as possible so I don't muddy the waters too much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should probably consider approaching the problem at hand differently. I do not know the details of your problem, but from the information you've given, I think the following might be a feasible solution:

1. Create a `ConfigurationBase` class which contains the common properties of the 10 classes.
2. Rather than having the `Configuration` property be of type `String`, let it be generic, i.e: `T`. Consequently, your view model should be a generic type as well, where the type parameter should be constrained to `ConfigurationBase` and `new()` (because it should be serialized/deserialized).
3. Now that your class is generic, you do not need the `ConfigurationType` property, so remove it.
4. Create an editor for each subclass of `ConfigurationBase`.
5. Optionally, you could create a method on your view model which serializes the configuration instance to a `String` if that's actually required.

Check the code below:

```
public class MyViewModel<T> where T : ConfigurationBase, new() 
{
   public T Configuration {get; set; }

   public String SerializeConfiguration() 
   {
      //return the serialized this.Configuration
   }
}
```